# How to handle subdirectories in a Front Controller pattern

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, front-controller

**TL;DR**: My URL rewriting breaks if a subdirectory without a file is requested. Instead of loading a default `home` page as expected, I'm getting a **403 Forbidden** error.

I'm using Apache URL rewriting to build a site using the Front Controller pattern. So far, my `.htaccess` looks like this:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(subdir|subdir/.*|subdir2|subdir2/.*).*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+) index.php?request=$1 [QSA]
```

So this is working for all requests except requests for subdirectories:

- `mydomain.com/` results in ->

  - `mydomain.com/index.php` with `home.inc` content
- `mydomain.com/page1` results in ->

  - `mydomain.com/index.php` with `/pages/page1.inc` content
- `mydomain.com/subdir/` results in ->

  - **`403 Forbidden`**
- `mydomain.com/subdir/page1` results in ->

  - `mydomain.com/index.php` with `/subdir/pages/page1.inc` content

More details below that probably don't matter, since the issue is likely in the `.htaccess`.

---

<sup>In `index.php`, I'm catching the request and using that to grab the corresponding include page from a directory `/pages` which has files with the content of each page. Here's the (somewhat simplified) code from `index.php`:</sup>

```
//grab the actual HTTP request
$request = $_GET['request'];

//if the request has slashes, isolate the directory part into $dir
$slashPos = strrpos($request, "/");
if($slashPos !== false){
    $dir = substr($request, 0, $slashPos) . "/";
    $page = basename($request, ".inc");
} else {
    $dir = "";
    $page = request;
}

//use "home" if no filename is specified.
if($page==""){$page="home";}

//build path to content include
$content = $dir . "pages/" . $page . ".inc";

//output page
require("header.php"); 
require($content ); 
require("footer.php");
```

<sup>This works perfect for the root directory. A request for `mydomain.com/page1` results in `mydomain.com/index.php` being served with the contents of `mydomain.com/pages/page1` included.</sup>

<sup>It also works for *pages* within a subdirectory: a request for `mydomain.com/subdir/page1` results in `mydomain.com/index.php` being served with the contents of `mydomain.com/subdir/pages/page1` included.</sup>

<sup>It all breaks when the request is for an actual directory. So `mydomain.com/subdir/` returns **403 Forbidden**. Why is it doing that? I expect it to load `$dir` with `subdir` and `$page` with `home` (I set as a default for when `$page==""`).</sup>

<sup>Yes, `Options -Indexes` is probably causing the `403`, but why only on subdirectories? It doesn't `403` on root. And the line `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(subdir|subdir/.*|subdir2|subdir2/.*).*$` in `.htaccess` should catch it, right?</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. The problem is that `subdir` wasn't actually at web root. My entire site is actually working in its own subdirectory. In other words, I wasn't working in

```
mydomain.com/
```

as the root, I was working in

```
mydomain.com/mydivision/
```

as a root. So obviously in this line:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(subdir|subdir/.*|subdir2|subdir2/.*).*$
```

the `^` made it look for `subdir` at the actual webroot. To fix I removed `^` or add my actual subdomain to that line after `^`.